# how do I find which packages build-depend on a certain package

Tags: debian, apt, dependencies

For instance when I run the command -

```
$ apt-rdepends --build-depends qbittorrent
```

it gives the output something like -

```
  Build-Depends: debhelper (>= 10)
  Build-Depends: dpkg-dev (>= 1.16.1)
  Build-Depends: libboost-dev
  Build-Depends: libqt5svg5-dev
  Build-Depends: libtorrent-rasterbar-dev (>= 1.1.2)
  Build-Depends: qtbase5-dev (>= 5.2.0)
  Build-Depends: qttools5-dev-tools
  Build-Depends: zlib1g-dev
```

But how do I find which packages for instance use libtorrent-rasterbar-dev which might be in other packages build-depends ? **Not** depends, recommends or suggests but is a requirement only in **build-depends**

Comment: I’m probably missing something in your question...

Comment: The question is closed as duplicate but it's not, really. You can find the list of reverse build dependencies with build-rdeps: https://manpages.debian.org/testing/devscripts/build-rdeps.1.en.html